# How do we import the complete schema of Xero in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, schema, xero-api, xero

I copied data from Xero api to mySQL database using the Xero connector in Azure data factory. However, The copied data did not contain all the data columns. I read in a documentation that Xero data is available through two schemas: Minimal (default) and Complete. The Complete schema contains prerequisite call tables which require additional data (e.g. ID column) before making the desired query. My question is, How do we import the complete schema in Azure data factory?

The minimal schema has Account code and not account ID in the invoice table. I need the Account ID to import account related data and I believe that the complete schema will have it. Could someone please help with this.

Comment: if you can't access tables in the complete schema through dataset, can you try using query options and give the required query in the query text box of copy activity. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/VQWkZpp.png)

Comment: Hi Aswin, I tried using a query in the copy activity but the table unfortunately is the same.

Comment: **but the table unfortunately is the same** -- Could you explain this in detail? What does this mean?

Comment: The Journal table on zero has columns like 'source ID' when I call it on postman. But in the ADF copy activity, It does not populate as the default schema of Xero connector is the minimal schema. As you mentioned I tried querying the table instead of copying it as a Table and the Source ID column is still missing.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the source settings, with the query

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjJrJ.png

Comment: Why didn't you use `select * from Complete.<table-name>`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac8Vc.png . It says table not found.

Comment: Does this table exists in complete schema?

Comment: Yes. It exists. I have been searching some docs to find how to use the complete schema and unable to find one. 

The doc says just this

The following tables can only be queried with complete schema:

Complete.Bank_Transaction_Line_Items
Complete.Bank_Transaction_Line_Item_Tracking
.....

Comment: @Nirmal were you able to find anything useful regarding this?

Comment: No. I used a different technique to directly query the Xero REST API inside ADF for some specific tables.

Comment: Can you share it here?

Comment: I used the REST Service and accessed the api source without using the Native ADF Connector for those Tables which i need all data.

Then used the same access_token for this REST API Service and pulled the data by querying the data using the resource endpoint